# PHP move/copy temp file into a new directory and rename it ( performance )

Tags: php, file, copy, move, scp

i simply upload file from a html form.

Now , once the file is uploaded php creates a temp file somewhere.

I was wondering, is it faster to copy or move the file into a new directory?

I saw these three methods available `ssh2_scp_send()` `copy()` `move_uploaded_file();` , can someone explain differences between these methods and which is faster at the end?

For each method i will go for using, i will need to rename the file anyway so the combination is copy or move + rename file.

> At the end, is here a really faster solution, to move or copy file
>   from a dir to another and rename it?

thank you

Comment: Move would be logical, you don't usually want to keep 2 copies of the same file unnecessarily on the server But you really have to benchmark it in order to find out which is faster

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ thank you but i need the faster one, logic for now doesn't matter since then i delete both files...

Comment: Move is faster than copy, because for move all you need is an update partition table no need to copy data

Comment: @DevZer0 do you mean scp or move_uploaded_file()? :)

Comment: why do you need scp unless your copying across network. i am talking in file system wise move is faster than a copy as long as its done to the same partition

Comment: @DevZer0 just wondering if scp could be faster nothing more :D

Answer (score 3):

Use `move_uploaded_file()` its the most simple method to move an uploaded file to its proper destination.

In general a file move is much faster than file copy (in the same partition) because with move there is no actual file data being moved, only the `fat` is updated.

Comment: ok, but what about ssh moving ? (obviously the connection will be pre-established) ...

Comment: ssh moving to the localhost?

Comment: yeah ssh from same server :D , crazy? :D

Answer (score 0):

Move would be as faster than  copy...

To move a file use the [rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function.

To move an uploaded file move_uploaded_file is the way to go. It has a little overhead in that it check and ensures that the file was in fact the result of an upload.

Comment: so rename will move a temp file to a new directory with new name? :O

Comment: Yes you supply it with the tmp file and the new file. for your case move_uploaded_file is probably the route to go.

Comment: so can't i use rename to copy and rename file from tmp to new directory? or you suggest move_uploaded_file() cause it's faster? sorry i didn't catched you

Comment: you can use either... but since you are moving a file that was uploaded then move_uploaded_file is probably a better solution.

Comment: From the docs about the upload check - `This sort of check is especially important if there is any chance that anything done with uploaded files could reveal their contents to the user, or even to other users on the same system.`

Comment: what is the upload check sorry? i mean i will not show the images to user i will just copy them and do other stuffs on thm later, so should i go for rename instead of move_uploaded_file ?